# Get the first JSON result

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to grab the url for featured_image. How do I go about this?

result["featured_image"] ...

```
featured_image: [
"http://192.168.23.23/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/formal_table.jpg",
984,
500,
false
]
```

Comment: `result["featured_image"][0]`?  It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried `result["featured_image"] [0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `featured_image` is an `array` you could use the following,

```
result["featured_image"][0]
```

to access the `URL`, that is in the zeroth index of that `array`.

Comment: When I type result["featured_image"] it outputs ["http://192.168.23.23/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/formal_table.jpg", 984, 500, false] .. when I type result["featured_image"][0]  I only get an error, it doesn't allow me to access the first item.

Comment: @Michael It should work. What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @Michael Your array seems invalid. Did you see the semicolen after the url? `........table.jpg";,`

Comment: I'm extending WP-API to add the featured image in the plugin. I'm using Ruby on Rails as a front end and when i output featured_image[0] in rails, it causes and error. So I added featured_image[0] in the plugin and it outputs only the URL which I can just grab it. normally without the [0]. This is the right answer though. Thank you!